# How do you set the data function for a Kendo DataSource using the Razor HTML Helpers?

Tags: c#, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get the Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC grid control working with a WebApi controller using OData queries. I would prefer to emit the relevant javascript using the Html helpers but I'm struggling to emit the equivalent of this:

```js
schema: { data: function (data) { return data; } }
```

I've tried this:

```
.Schema(schema => schema.Data((object data) => { return data; }))
```

But I'm getting

> Error: 'Kendo' is undefined

in IE and the actual JS emitted is:

```js
"schema":{"data":Kendo.Mvc.ClientHandlerDescriptor}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A bit difficult to debug your issue without full code, but it should probably look like this:

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Custom()
    .Schema(schema => schema.Data(data => data))
    .Type("odata")
    .Transport(t => t.Read("MyAction", "My")))
```

Comment: I did try that and it didn't seem to work, I've given up on the Html helper and I'm just writing the JavaScript instead.

Comment: I stumbled across this when struggling the same problem, the above works if you change `data => data` to `data => "data"`