# How can I specify schema for Kendo using helper?

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have my data coming inside a data variable "data" which contains the array of all the data that I want to feed to Multi Select. I know there is a thing called schema which specifies he field in json which contains the data. I have already tried

.Schema(schema => schema.Data((object data) => { return data; }))

and also tried without the helper. Can somebody please tell the syntax for defining the schema with the helper. This is the error I get

Kendo is not defined

I know this is same question as
[How do you set the data function for a Kendo DataSource using the Razor HTML Helpers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832460/how-do-you-set-the-data-function-for-a-kendo-datasource-using-the-razor-html-hel)

but that question is also still unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Telerik tech support,

> Generally speaking, this is not supported by the MultiSelect MVC
>   wrapper and
>       its dataSource always expects a collection, but can be achieved by overriding the
>       reader.data function e.g.
>
> ```
>     multiselect.dataSource.reader.data = function (data) { return data.values};
> ```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering.I had this query because their official docs state that Schema is allowed http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/multiselect/overview Go to the Schema portion. They redirect to a page on how to define data.